# JavaScript: Initialize Object array with invalid index

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

For example, I create constructor and initialize array of objects (JS)

```
function SomeConstruct(val1, val2) {
    this.val1= val1;
    this.val2= val2;
}


var someCons= new Array();
someCons[0] = new SomeConstruct(12, 40);
someCons[1] = new SomeConstruct(34, 42);
someCons[2] = new SomeConstruct(0,-5);
```

And then I create new object with index [5] though last index of array is [2]

```
someCons[5]=new SomeConstruct(43,232);
```

But this code works, but when I try to access objects [3] or [4] I get error

How can I prevent this behavior - for instance I have some loop where I add new  objects to the array with some condition ( val1==1) but at some point this logic breaks and I miss some index of array as above and create [5] instead of [3] element ?
Why does JS allows this kind of behavior ?

Comment: Any string will serve as a property name for a JavaScript object.

Comment: I believe you will find your answer here: [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771001/how-best-to-do-a-javascript-array-with-non-consecutive-indexes)  In short, use an object instead of an array if you want and the you can use the for-in enumeration to get the data back out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I prevent this behavior

Use the [`push` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add an element to an array, instead of assigning to a fixed index that might be beyond the actual array.

> Why does JS allows this kind of behavior?

Because [arrays in JS are sparse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1510778/1048572). After all, you could always have an `undefined` value in array of objects. If you really have to deal with them, you will need to jump over the missing indices in your iteration (`forEach` does that as well).

Answer (score 1):

an alternative to using the `push` methods above is -

```
someCons[someCons.length] = new SomeConstruct(val, val);
```

which does the same thing - adding the new construct to the current last position in the array.

Answer (score 0):

In the JavaScript if you assign value to some random index of Array the following behavior, I tried this code on browser console :

```
a = new Array(10);
```

[undefined × 10]

```
a = new Array()
```

[]

```
a.length
```

0

```
a[10] = "a"
```

"a"

```
a[1]="b"
```

"b"

```
a
```

[undefined × 1, "b", undefined × 8, "a"]

```
a[20]=30;
```

30

```
a
```

[undefined × 1, "b", undefined × 8, "a", undefined × 9, 30]

To prevent this you can push your element in the Array like

```
var arrSomeCons= new Array();
someCons = new SomeConstruct(12, 40);
arrSomeCons.push(someCons)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, when the last index of array is [2] and you create new object in [5], [3] and [4] become undefined, because you didn't declare them. If you want to do it successively and don't miss any indexes, you can use push, or use code like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  array[i] = new Constr();
```

or

```
for(some conditions to declare variables)
   array.push(new Constr(variables));
```

or

```
array.push( elem1, elem2, ... )
```