# Data is not updated when using as object, but changes normally when it's a variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm writing a function to update a custom checkbox when clicked (and I don't want to use native checkbox for some reasons).

The code for checkbox is

```html
<div class="tick-box" :class="{ tick: isTicked }" @click="() => isTicked = !isTicked"></div>
```

which works find.

However, there are so many checkboxes, so I [use object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771001/how-best-to-do-a-javascript-array-with-non-consecutive-indexes) to keep track for each item. It looks like this

```html
<!-- (inside v-for) -->
<div class="tick-box" :class="{ tick: isTicked['lyr'+layer.lyr_id] }" @click="() => {
  isTicked['lyr'+layer.lyr_id] = !isTicked['lyr'+layer.lyr_id]
}"></div>
```

Now nothing happens, no error at all.

When I want to see `isTicked` value with `{{ isTicked }}`, it's just shows `{}`.

This is what I define in the `<script></script>` part.

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isTicked: {},
      ...
    };
  },
  ...
}
```

Could you help me where I get it wrong?

Thanks!

Edit:

I know that declaring as `isTicked: {}`, the first few clicks won't do anything because its proerty is undefined. However, it should be defined by the first/second click not something like this.

Comment: I think it might work better to use an array with `ticked` values, and then use `v-for` to render all the checkboxes.

Comment: Read for object change detection: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Object-Change-Detection-Caveats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects does not reflect the changes when updated like this.
You should use $set to set object properties in order to make them reactive.
Try as below

```
   <div class="tick-box" :class="{ tick: isTicked['lyr'+layer.lyr_id] }" @click="onChecked"></div>
```

Add below method:

```
onChecked() {
  this.$set(this.isTicked,'lyr'+this.layer.lyr_id, !this.isTicked['lyr'+this.layer.lyr_id])
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me.

I modified this to oncheck(lyr_id) and use that in the function instead, i.e., `this.$set(this.isTicked,'lyr'+lyr_id, !this.isTicked['lyr'+lyr_id])` since `this.layer` is not in the scope.

Answer (score 0):

VueJS watches data by reference so to update object in state you need create new one.

```
onChecked(lyr_id) {
    const key = 'lyr'+lyr_id;
    this.isTicked = {...this.isTicked, [key]: !this.isTicked[key]};
}
```