# How to update state of 2D array with N objects inside in React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-vis

Before I jump on subject, I want to mention that I've already referred to questions like these, but could not figure the solution on my own.

[Updating React state as a 2d array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57147297/updating-react-state-as-a-2d-array)

Let's assume this is my state object

```
state = {
    graphData: [
        [{x: 0, y: 0}],
    ],
};
```

As time increases, graphData will get bigger and might look something like this

```
    graphData: [
        [{x: 0, y: 0}, {x: 1, y:1}, {x:2, y:2}],
    ],
```

At the moment, I handle that in this manner:

```
  nextGraphData = this.state.graphData[0][graphDataLength] = {x: lastXAxisValue + 1, y: value};

    this.setState({
        graphData: {
            ...this.state.graphData,
            nextGraphData
        }
    });
```

Obviously, I get an error saying I should not mutate state directly. So, how to achieve the same without direct mutation. I tried to play around a bit, but could not figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
state = {
    graphData: [
        [{x: 0, y: 0}],
    ],
};
```

use like this

```
this.setState({
  ...this.state,
  graphData: [...this.state.graphData, {x:1,y:1}]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The error appears because of this line

```
nextGraphData = this.state.graphData[0][graphDataLength] = {x: lastXAxisValue + 1, y: value};
```

as you are trying to assign value directly to the `state.graphData`

what you have to do is to change it like this:

let nextGraphData = {...this.state.graphData,{x: lastXAxisValue + 1, y: value}};

```
this.setState({
    graphData: {
        ...nextGraphData
    }
});
```